# Subquery returned more than 1 value for select query using case

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use the select query with `case` in it & following error message appeared:

> ```
> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
> follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> ```

below is my query:

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN (SELECT VALUE FROM ORDER WHERE VALUE > 0 AND VALUE < 1000) < 1000
     THEN 'B1'
WHEN (SELECT VALUE FROM ORDER WHERE VALUE > 1001 AND VALUE < 2000) < 2000
     THEN 'B2'
ELSE 'B3'
END
FROM ORDER
```

Comment: why have you tagged both MySQL and SQLServer? - Also this query makes no sense, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Steve, really sorry for that. It is SQL-Server. Can you pls guide me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the subquery for?  You are selecting from the same table in the subquery as in the outer query.  In the context, the subquery needs to be a *scalar subquery* that returns only one column and at most one row.

I suspect that you want this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN VALUE > 0 AND VALUE < 1000 THEN 'B1'
             WHEN VALUE > 1001 AND VALUE < 2000 THEN 'B2'
             ELSE 'B3'
        END)
FROM ORDER
```

EDIT:  You can easily turn this into an aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN VALUE > 0 AND VALUE < 1000 THEN 'B1'
             WHEN VALUE > 1001 AND VALUE < 2000 THEN 'B2'
             ELSE 'B3'
        END), COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM ORDER o
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN VALUE > 0 AND VALUE < 1000 THEN 'B1'
               WHEN VALUE > 1001 AND VALUE < 2000 THEN 'B2'
               ELSE 'B3'
          END);
```

Note that `Order` is a really, really bad name for a table because it conflicts with a SQL reserved word.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am looking for sum of all order value which falls in given value range. This is for some reporting purpose. Thanks once again.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, for your help & quick response. This has really helped a lot. Really appreciated.